# Issue with PHP web service response

Tags: php, web-services

I created a web service in php which returns JSON. It works fine but it is not consistent most of the times it pulls all the information needed other times it leaves out a specific column which is the second to last table named table_bio. I thought it was a caching issue however I put in the relevant headers in apache and within the service and still no luck. Thing is that the service is getting the correct information but not returning the correct info.

Below is my code:

```
<?php
 error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
 $id = $_GET['Table'];
 /* grab the posts from the db */
 $query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE table_id='$id'";
 $result = mysql_query($query,$link) or die('Errant query:  '.$query);

 /* create one master array of the records */
 while($post = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {    $posts = $post;       } 
 /* output in necessary format */
 header('Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate'); // HTTP 1.1.
 header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
 header('Pragma: no-cache'); // HTTP 1.0.
 header('Expires: 0'); // Proxies.
 header('Content-type: application/json');
 echo $_GET['onJSONPLoad'];
 echo "(" . json_encode($posts) . ")";
 @mysql_close($link);
 ?>
```

Any ideas as to why this is happening?

I should also mention the column that is not showing sometimes is of type text

Comment: You can not output non-json data when `application/json` type is used. Why do you output `$_GET['onJSONPLoad'];`? And why do you use `( )`?

Comment: Can you give a better example please. I got this from a a tutorial I was following

Comment: Just output with `echo json_encode($posts);` only.

Comment: And escape your table `id`.

Comment: how do I escape the `id`?

Comment: I tired everything and the same column is returning null when there is data within the column. If i try the same query within phpmyadmin it returns all the results. This issue is quite strange

Comment: The solution to my issue can be found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11343925/json-encode-for-mysql-query-returns-some-null-columns-of-some-rows-but-the-colu